# Bernoulli measure is aperiodic

Tags: probability-distributions, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $\Sigma=\{s_1,\dots,s_m\}$ be a finite list of symbols, and put $X=\Sigma^\mathbb{Z}$.

Consider the left two-sided shift $T:X\to X$ given by $T(x_n)=(x_{n+1})$. Given an $m$-dimensional vector $\vec{p}=(p_1,\dots,p_m)$, we can construct a measure on $\Sigma$ by $\sum_{i=1}^m p_i \delta_{s_i}$, which then generates an infinite product measure on $X$. Such a measure is called a Bernoulli shift, and is ergodic for $T$.

A measure is called aperiodic if set of periodic points has zero measure.

**Question**

Bernoulli measure is aperiodic?

Comment: Hint: can you show that there are countably many periodic points in $X$? Now all you need to show is that the measure of any countable set is zero for the Bernoulli measure.

Comment: @DanRust    any periodic sequence with a repeating an block of length
n defines and periodic orbit. The set of all periodic sequences is countable.I can show that measure any countable set is zero but for Bernoulli measure,i do not know.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x_i)_{i \geq 1}$ be a countable subset of $X$ and let $$B_{i,k} = \{x \in X \mid (x)_{[-k,k]} = (x_{i})_{[-k,k]}\}$$ be the cylinder set of length $k$ which contains $x_i$.

Show that $$B(n) := \bigcup_{i=0}^\infty B_{i,n2^i}$$ is a nested sequences of subsets that contains every $x_i$ for any value of $n$ and then show that the measure of $B(n)$ converges to $0$ as $n$ increases. Hence, what must the measure of $\{x_i \mid i \geq 0\}$ be?